# WildFly in domain mode. How to get http port from code

Tags: java, wildfly

Anybody knows how to get http port from application deployed on Wildfly (14) in domain mode?

Comment: For example if you have 2 servers in domain mode running the same application, at localhost:8080  you want to see '8080' and at localhost:8230 you want to see '8230'. And you are trying to do that with your java code. Is this what you are looking for?